# USB fan controller

Tags: usb, fan, temperature

I'd like to control the speed of 3 fans:

- CPU fan (3-pin fan connector; connected to mainboard)
- 2x chassis fan (3-pin fan connector; connected to power supply via molex adapter)

Unfortunately, it seems that my mainboard (Intel DG45FC) doesn't allow to control the CPU fan: "sudo pwmconfig" gives "There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed". lspci output: http://pastie.org/6197353

Is there a USB fan controller (for sale, no DIY), which lets ubuntu control three or more 3-pin fans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need the PWM line to control the fan speed. This simply achieved by controlling the voltage of each fan.

This guy designed a board which controls up to 4 fans. Unfortunately you will have to write your own scripts to use it properly:
http://geoffg.net/fancontroller.html

If this is too complicated, you could go for a "fan controller". These are sold by many fan manufacturers and fit in 3.5" bays. Example: Scythe Kaze Q or Scythe Kaze Master.

If price isn't an issue, there is also this thing:
http://www.sidewindercomputers.com/aqlt4wdiandc.html

Comment: http://www.bitfenix.com/global/en/products/accessories/recon/

Comment: The Bitfenix Recon even comes with an open source control software called phoebetria